# How to pass page index.html and the req.params.id back to the client

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm using express and Angular. I want to send the page (index.html) *and* one paramter that will be the ID used to determine which youtube video to load in that page.

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res){
    //send index page + extractYoutubeVideoCode(req.params.id)
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
});
```

I'm not sure I want to use a template render engine like jade if I've got angular on the front end - but maybe that's the answer

I suspect I can't use # routes with angular as people will be reaching the pages with a link like localhost:3000/TUj0otkJEBi

How should I go about passing the page index.html and the req.params.id back to the client

Answer (score 0):

Will you can use the ui-router plugin to anguler to do this. It helps to navigate in states same as we can do that in backbone and jade but it is not an overhead but can be used as an integral part of angular.

please look here for more details feel free to reply if you find problem in my solution or you need something else.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: could you go into any more detail on this?

Comment: you can create the template for the html page which will be like another html page without head and body tag and then you can provide a state to the page as given in the example in the link given in solution. then when you click on the link or send a request to server with some id the page will be handled automatically by the ui-router and will be fetched with appropriate content please go through the tutorial in the link given in answer